# dependencies issue in apache nutch

Tags: java, mapreduce, nutch

Trying to integrate apache nutch with hadoop. After building apache-nutch-1.15.job file which resides in runtime folder using ant and tried to run the script bin/crawl but got some dependency errors.
Can see all the required dependencies embedded in it when extracted the .job file. Also there are no issues with versions of the dependencies which are embedded.

```
sh crawl -s <seed_file_directory_on_hdfs> <crawl_directory_on_hdfs> <num_rounds>

19/03/22 01:41:22 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job:job_1547155431533_115992
19/03/22 01:41:34 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1547155431533_115992 running 
in uber mode : false
19/03/22 01:41:34 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
19/03/22 01:41:45 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : 
attempt_1547155431533_115992_r_000001_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: x point 
org.apache.nutch.net.URLNormalizer not found.
    at org.apache.nutch.net.URLNormalizers.<init>(URLNormalizers.java:146) 
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Generator$SelectorReducer.setup(Generator.java:378)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:168)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:627)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1924)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

Tried giving those extracted jars in classpath path by changing the script but it didn't helped and the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of apache nutch is not updated since 2014.

To crawl a web page using apache nutch build the project using ant and execute the commands mentioned to crawl to local file system (https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial) by replacing all local paths with hdfs paths (If you want to crawl content and dump onto hdfs)